# cannot get conversations of facebook page with API version 2.4

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.4

I'm trying to read conversations of my page but after creating a new "TestApp" on facebook I am not able to read the conversations of my page.

I used the Graph API Explorer for generating the Page Access Token but when I try to get the conversations of my page, the calls (graph.facebook.com/{my_page_id}/conversations) returns only the following fields: **updated_time, link, id**.

How can I retrieve the messages of any conversation_id returned by API? The API version used are 2.4.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_changes, “declarative fields”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In v2.4 you need to declare the fields you want in the response.

To retrieve all fields from the conversations endpoint you need to execute the following:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/{page-id}/conversations?fields=snippet,updated_time,message_count,unread_count, tags, participants,senders,can_reply,is_subscribed

References

1. Declarative Fields https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_changes
2. Conversation Endpoint https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/conversation/